# Stored procedures returning null value in razor pages

Tags: stored-procedures, razor-pages

I have two stored procedures which will execute based on a condition.

First stored procedure : `AvailableHourSlots`:

```
CREATE PROCEDURE [dbo].[AvailableHourSlots] 
    @ActivityName nvarchar(max) ,
    @BookedDate datetime2(7)
AS  
    SELECT DISTINCT HourlyBasedTime 
    FROM ManageBooking AS mb, HourlyBased AS hb  
    WHERE bookingdate = @BookedDate 
      AND ActivityName = @ActivityName
      AND (SUBSTRING(HourlyBasedTime, 1, 2) <> SUBSTRING(mb.PreferredTimeslot, 1, 2))
```

Second stored procedure : `AvailableHalfAnHourSlots`:

```
CREATE PROCEDURE [dbo].[AvailableHalfAnHourSlots] 
    @ActivityName nvarchar(max) ,
    @BookedDate datetime2(7)
AS  
    SELECT DISTINCT hh.halfanhourtime
    FROM ManageBooking AS mb, Halfanhour hh
    WHERE bookingdate = @BookedDate
      AND ActivityName = @ActivityName 
      AND (SUBSTRING(hh.halfanhourtime, 1, 5) <> SUBSTRING(mb.PreferredTimeslot, 1, 5))
      AND (RIGHT(hh.halfanhourtime, 5) <> RIGHT(mb.PreferredTimeslot, 5))
```

Model created based on the first stored procedure output:

```
namespace ActivityBookingSystem.Models
{
    public class HourlyBasedView
    {
        public string HourlyBasedTime { get; set; }   
    }
}
```

`ApplicationDbContext`:

```
protected override void OnModelCreating(ModelBuilder modelBuilder)
{            
    modelBuilder.Entity<NonOperatingDaysView>().HasNoKey();
    modelBuilder.Entity<AvailableOneHourSlots>().HasNoKey();
    modelBuilder.Entity<HourlyBasedView>().HasNoKey();

    //modelBuilder.Ignore<HourlyBasedView>(); //ignore create the table for the stored procedure
    //modelBuilder.Query<HourlyBasedView>();            
}

public DbSet<ActivityBookingSystem.Models.HourlyBasedView> HourlyBasedView { get; set; }
```

`create.cshtml` - Ajax call:

```
function GetAvailableSlots(e) {
        var rootPath = '@Url.Content("~")';
        alert("Hi");
        var ActivityList = document.getElementById("DrpDwnActivityList");
        var ActivityListValue = ActivityList.options[ActivityList.selectedIndex].value;
        var BookedDate = document.getElementById("DateBookedDate").value;
        
        $.ajax({
            type: "Get",
            url: rootPath + "/ManageBooking/Create?handler=GetAvailableSlots",
            headers: { "RequestVerificationToken": $('input[name="__RequestVerificationToken"]').val() },
            data: { Duration: e.value,ActivityName:ActivityListValue,BookedDate:BookedDate },
            dataType: "json",
            success: function (result) {
                //console.log(result),  //just for debug
                //    $("#TrainingType").val(result.trainingType), //mind this should be lower-case letters by default setting
                //    $("#TrainingVersion").val(result.version),
                //    $("#SessionType").val(result.sessionType)
                alert(result);
            },
            error: function (data) {
                alert(data);
            }
        });
    }
```

`create.cshtml.cs`:

```
public async Task<JsonResult> OnGetGetAvailableSlotsAsync(string ActivityName, string BookedDate, string Duration)
{
    Console.WriteLine(Duration);
    DateTime BookingDate = Convert.ToDateTime(BookedDate);
    ActivityName = ActivityName.ToString();
            
    if (Duration == "1 Hour")
    {
        var LstPreferredTimeSlot = _context.HourlyBasedView.FromSqlRaw("EXEC dbo.AvailableHourSlots @BookingDate = {0}, @ActivityName = {1}", BookingDate, ActivityName)
                    .AsNoTracking().ToList();

        // var PreferredTimeSlot = await _context.HourlyBasedView.FromSqlRaw($"SELECT distinct HourlyBasedTime  FROM   ManageBooking as mb, HourlyBased as hb  WHERE bookingdate = {BookingDate} and ActivityName = {ActivityName} and (substring(HourlyBasedTime,1,2) <> substring(mb.PreferredTimeslot,1,2))").ToListAsync();
    }

    return new JsonResult(LstPreferredTimeSlot);
}
```

The stored procedure is returning null value, I executed the query separately in SQL Server Management Studio, it's returning the value.

Any help would be appreciated!

---

Edited create.cshtml.cs

---

```
if (Duration == "1 Hour")
            {
                var LstPreferredTimeSlot = _context.HourlyBasedView.FromSqlRaw("EXEC dbo.AvailableHourSlots @BookedDate = {0}, @ActivityName = {1}", BookingDate, ActivityName).
                    AsNoTracking().ToList();

                

                
            }
```

Comment: [Bad habits to kick : using old-style JOINs](https://sqlblog.org/2009/10/08/bad-habits-to-kick-using-old-style-joins) - that old-style *comma-separated list of tables* style was replaced with the *proper* ANSI `JOIN` syntax in the ANSI-**92** SQL Standard (more than **30 years!!** ago) and its use is discouraged

Comment: Double check that you are passing the parameter values that you think are being passed.

Comment: @MikeBrind Thank you so much Mike, Managed to fix the issue, you are correct, the parameter value for BookedDate was wrong.

Answer (score 0):

Date parameter was passed wrongly. Corrected version is as shown below

```
if (Duration == "1 Hour")
{
  var LstPreferredTimeSlot = _context.HourlyBasedView.FromSqlRaw("EXEC dbo.AvailableHourSlots @BookedDate = {0}, @ActivityName = {1}", BookingDate, ActivityName).AsNoTracking().ToList();                    
}
```